# Close A Wallsystem in archpack

Tags: add-on, archipack-add-on

I have a simple question about the archipack addon.

I want to create a complex floor with several rooms etc. now I'm trying do draw the surrounding walls, but how can I close the wall system of the surrounding walls?
[image: Screen of my project, the drawing on the ground is da incscape svg sratch]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only when the walls are finished with a right click will the checkbox to close under the properties window show up.

Comment: You also should be able to use the "C" key while drawing to close your wall.

Answer (score 0):

Select your wall object and click the 'close' option under Base line in the Archipack options. (You'll notice that splitting your wall later causes this to be untoggled again)

[image: Close toggle]